# MAC A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, macos, maven, java-8, runtime-error

Running tests in Chrome browser, it suddenly crashes on the same step with this error:
fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment in Intelij Idea (2016.2.2) https://www.refheap.com/122660

and MAC throws this kind of report https://www.refheap.com/122658 If I run mvn package - it crashes with error ForkedBooter quit unexpectedly

Using Java jdk1.8.0_45.jdk with JUnit and Maven.

Can you please help me to find out, what causes this problem?

Comment: Here is a log file from Intelij Idea https://www.refheap.com/ad32ddd36b73356f492b12e9e

Comment: Updated java version to 1.8.0_60 - and error gone.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a shell terminal and type in:

`export LD_BIND_NOW=1`

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your log snippet, the cause of your error is located in your project directory, specifically:

```
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/irisha/IdeaProjects/myproject/hs_err_pid502.log
```

As to the cause of your error, please note that IntelliJ has some restrictions on what your page can access.  Installing the [JetBrains Chrome Extension](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/06/cors-control-in-jetbrains-chrome-extension/) may help although the cause could be a number of things.  The `hs_err_pid<id>.log` should help identify that.

If the cause turns out to be an underlying JDK issue, you can submit a bug report to Oracle here: http://bugs.java.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the suggestion provided in error message

```
Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Try after [enabling core dumping](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH54279). To verify core dumping

```
 ulimit -a
 ulimit -c unlimited 
 ulimit -c 1024
```